# Calling a specific user to create a notification? (wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2))

Tags: ruby-on-rails

ArgumentError in UsersController#remove
wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2)

Users type teachers can be added and removed from a classroom. When they are added they get a notification. When they are removed, they get a notification. Except, when removing them I get an error.

ArgumentError in UsersController#remove
wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2)
Line: def remove_teacher_notification(classroom, teacher)

Now I think I know why this is happening, it's detecting all classroom teachers as teachers, and not just the teacher being removed. So, because there are two teachers in a class, that makes 3 arguments given.

Here is my code:
Users Controller

```
def remove
    ## Find the join table where the teacher and classroom match
    join_table = ClassroomTeacher.where(teacher_id: @teacher, classroom_id: @classroom)
    ## If so, remove the teacher from the classroom by deleting the join table
    ## This will remove the association between the teacher and the classroom
    if join_table
      @teacher.classroom_teachers.delete(join_table)
      remove_teacher_notification @classroom, @teacher, notice: "Notification sent"
      redirect_to classroom_path(@classroom), notice: 'Teacher was successfully removed.'
    end
  end



def remove_teacher_notification(classroom, teacher)
    Notification.create(user_id: teacher.id,
                        notified_by_id: current_user.id,
                        identifier: classroom.id,
                        notice_type: 'remove')
  end
```

It can successfully remove a teacher, but it won't create a notification correctly. Not quite sure how to define teachers. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `remove_teacher_notification` with 3 arguments but method definitions states it takes 2.

`@classroom` is the first arg, `@teacher` the second, and `notice: "Notification sent"` hash is the third. From what I see the third one is not intended to be used, so probably you put it there by accident.

Or it should be passed to `Notification.create` in the same fashion as `notice_type`

Comment: I remember setting this as a test to see if it was calling the method, forgot to take it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> ArgumentError in UsersController#remove wrong number of arguments
>   (given 3, expected 2)

The `remove_teacher_notification` expects **two** *arguments* but you are passing **three**.

```
remove_teacher_notification @classroom, @teacher, notice: "Notification sent"
```

Fix the `remove_teacher_notification` to accept *third argument*

```
def remove_teacher_notification(classroom, teacher, notice)
    Notification.create(user_id: teacher.id,
                        notified_by_id: current_user.id,
                        identifier: classroom.id,
                        notice_type: 'remove')
  end
```